# resizableImageWithCapInsets / asset catalog slicing confuses units and pixels

Tags: ios, xcode

Apologies for posting an image-related question as a new user, I need more reputation in order to include pics in my post :)

I am trying to resize an image without scaling its corners. I tried using resizableImageWithCapInsets as well as slicing through an asset catalog (although the latter only supports a deployment target of iOS 7+, which really does not make it a solution option...). I am using an image named "ViewHeaderTest.png" which is 44x100 pixels. The caps/insets should be a 16x16 pixel square in each corner.

This is the code:

```
    UIImageView *headerTest = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ViewHeaderTest.png"]];
    headerTest.image = [headerTest.image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    headerTest.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 50);
```

Code as well as asset catalog slicing produce the same result for me, which, oddly, does not appear mentioned anywhere else on stackoverflow: The caps / insets work fine, but they are scaled to double their original size. Basically it appears that resizableImageWithCapInsets takes returns an image of twice its original proportions.

Any takers? :)

Comment: Additional info: The problem persists in all three ways of slicing that I am familiar with:
1) Scaling through Interface Builder
2) Asset catalog slicing
3) Porgrammatically.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

As suspected, this is a retina issue. To avoid xcode confusing retina and non-retina images when using cap insets,

- Specity image name without file extension, i.e. @"FileName" instead of @"FileName.png"
- Have retina AND "normal" version of the file in corresponding resolutions in your project. I.e. have FileName.png (100px x 100 px) AND FileName@2x.png (200px x 200px) in the project.

I'm happy that it works, so I have not checked if either of these is redundant :)